# Wondering what should I do if the length of an array is even

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have written a code to find a middle element from a sorted array. Here is some part of my code:

```
Java Code:
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
int x = a.length;
        if (x % 2 != 0){
            int mid = 0 + x/2;
            System.out.println("The Middle Element is : " + a[mid]);
        }
```

I'm getting the output properly but wondering what should I write in the else condition of the code above? In other words, what should I do to find a middle element if a.length is even? Is this possible?

Comment: I have seen people returning either both or one of the middle elements, when the length is even...depends on the problem, since there is no specific middle element in this case.

Comment: @Bill Did you mean to say that if I have `int[] a = {1,2,3,4}`, one should return `2 and 3`?

Comment: Yes, I have seen people doing that...it depends on the problem you have.

Comment: @AaK, 'what you should do' depends on what algorithm you need to find the middle element for. If it's just for personal curiosity, any answer is OK.

Comment: It depends. What is the definition in your domain of `middle element`.  An element which has the same amount of elements before and after? If so, there is no such `middle element`. Is a middle element the element that is in the size/2, then whatever element is on there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can't answer that for you.  It depends on your requirements.  Here are some options:

- Return the two middle ones.
- Return the earlier option that's in the middle.
- Throw an exception that the method can't be called on an even length.
- etc.

Comment: Another is to return the average of the two middles

Comment: @Patashu Of course.  There's no right thing.

Comment: @tieTYT Rather, there are various right things. But there's no Right Thing™.

Answer (score 4):

There is no correct answer to this - the middle of an even number of values does not exist in a singular sense - the middle is between the 2 middle values.  The answer depends on what you want to achieve - we cannot tell you to take the lower, higher or both of the middle values because we do not know what you want to do with them.  Broadly speaking, you have 5 options, but only you can make the choice unless you give us more context on what you are trying to do here:

- Return the lower middle value.
- Return the higher middle value.
- Return both of the above values.
- Throw an exception.
- Do nothing (which is what your code does now).

Answer (score 2):

For the other way, you have to take the total divised by 2 (if you want the entire inferior (2 for 5 elements) or +1 to have the supperior (3 for 5 elements)

you can do directly :

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};

int x = a.length;
int mid = (int) x/2;
System.out.println("The Middle Element is : " + a[mid]);
```

Here is for have the middle or the inferior element when you dont have middle

You can do exception too to know in top level element if you don't have middle element and catch it when you have to.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically speaking, the typical, common solution to finding the median of an even set of numbers, is to calculate the mean of the two middlemost numbers. (An easy explanation is here: http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Median-of-a-Set-of-Numbers)

But as everyone is saying, there is no correct answer.
Personally, I'd go for the average option, but make sure you change your output statement to make it perfectly clear to the user that this is an average, and not an actual number.

Answer (score 0):

There is if-less code for both, for yielding the average of (both) middle elements:

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5, ...};

int x = a.length;
int mid = x / 2;
int mid2 = (x + 1) / 2; // Possibly the same as mid
int middleValue = (a[mid] + a[mid2]) / 2;
System.out.println("The Middle Element is : " + middleValue);
```